# Flutter textTheme property is not working, How to replace or fix it?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter. I just created a theme file to define light and dark theme.When I defined light theme, the `textTheme:`  property which is deprecated is not changing the text title  color of app bar into black.

If I have to create or define textTheme or replace it ?? How should I do it ?

```dart
class MyTheme {
  static ThemeData lightTheme(BuildContext context) => ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
      fontFamily: GoogleFonts.lato().fontFamily,
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),

//------
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme, // Problem is here
//------
      ));

  static ThemeData darkTheme(BuildContext context) =>
      ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this

```
textTheme: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.textTheme,
```

##### PS: It's deprecated. try to migrate.

Comment: Sorry, it is not working out.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `toolbarTextStyle` and `titleTextStyle` instead of using `textTheme` inside `appBarTheme`.

```dart
toolbarTextStyle:
    Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.toolbarTextStyle?.copyWith(
          color: Colors.amber,
          ///your config
        ),
titleTextStyle:
    Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.titleTextStyle?.copyWith(
          color: Colors.amber, ///your config
        )
```

More about [using theme](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes#using-a-theme).

Comment: ``` titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.titleTextStyle?.copyWith(   
          color: Colors.black,
        ), ```                           is not changig the title color

Comment: Can you include how you are using this style on Text?

Comment: I am using these following lines in MaterialApp widgets ```    theme: MyTheme.lightTheme(context),
        darkTheme: MyTheme.darkTheme(context), ```

Comment: I how you are using theme, Can you include your appBar code?

Comment: I fixed The problem using ```         titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black), ```. Thanks for your response.